# Google Chart error: b.L is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts

I did a little page with 3 graphics using the Google API.

Everything worked perfectly. However from one moment to the other crashed.

In the chart of the place appears this message: bL is not the function

Does someone can explain to me why this happens?

My example [working](http://jsfiddle.net/pX36k/1/):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', '2015');
        data.addColumn('number', '2014');
        data.addRows([
    ['Jan', 197680, 241921],
    ['Fev', 183619,205572],
    ['Mar', 205643,214666],
    ['Abr', 205643,202097],
    ['Mai', 0,210007],
    ['Jun', 0,202434],
    ['Jul', 0,217502],
    ['Ago', 0,175038],
    ['Set', 0,206510],
    ['Out', 0,209802],
    ['Nov', 0,197122],
    ['Dez', 0,162796]

]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Energia 2014/2015',
          titleTextStyle: {color: 'white', fontSize: '18'},
          chart_M: 'function',
          legend: {textStyle: {color: 'white'}},
          colors: ['#0099FF', '#11334c'],
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
          hAxis: {title: '', 
            textStyle: {
            color: '#C8C8C8' 
            }},
                vAxis: {title: '', 
            textStyle: {
            color: '#C8C8C8' 
            }}

        };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_energy'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

      }

    </script>
```

This is how it was working.

[image]

From one moment to the other was so.

[image]

Comment: I get no error in your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all reply.

I changed it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
```

and it works fine for me.

Is very strange, but the truth is that it was working.

Comment: I had a similar issue where the charts worked for over a year and then at some point this month (2016-04) it stopped.  The fix for me was to use the same version across packages.  I moved all to "1.1" but I don't remember why I had a mix of "1" and "1.1".  I'm using `google.load` not "autoload"

Answer (score 4):

Your page contains the `gauge`, `line` and `column` charts. So I'm presuming you have calls to `google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["gauge"]});` as well, in addition to `google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});`.

The different packages with separate load calls seemed to load fine until yesterday. But for some reason one or more packages aren't loading today which is why I was getting a similar exception.

Changing the separate load calls into one call like `google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart","gauge"]});` should make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem and it just started happening even though the chart was working earlier.

EDIT: I found that in my case google.load was called multiple times to load two different visualization packages. I've found out that if you load both packages at once it will resolve this error.