# Google charts different visualisation versions and the "b.L is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-api, google-visualization

I am generating a google PieChart script in php for statistics purposes and haven't changed the code in weeks because it worked. In the past few hours I've had periods of errors such as "b.L is not a function" or "undefined is not a function" and periods when it works properly. Also, the results were different when viewing from two different computers running Chrome/Ubuntu, fully updated with cleared Chrome caches. I can't change system services on the server-side, only my php code, which generates the html correctly.

I can provide an example, but suffices to use the default Google Pie Chart example from Google's Dev site.

It was suggested here in a similar example ([Google Chart error: b.L is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693920/google-chart-error-b-l-is-not-a-function)) that loading two different versions of google visualisation was the problem. Reverting to the same one indeed does solve my issue, but I can't understand why it's suddenly (as of 16 April 2015) necessary to do so. I never even realised I was using two different versions across the 6 graphs (3 line, 3 piechart) I had on my site.

Was there an update that was recently rolled out?

Thank you!

(I am posting this as a separate question since there might be an underlying problem which still isn't solved)