# google charts "is not a function" in every browser except chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-visualization

[image: a[jc] is not a function]

Firefox, safari, safari on ios, IE, ... all of them behave the same way.

no matter what I do, this error is only avoidable on the chrome browser.

Note that it is not a date formatting issue as I use

```
var rows = [
    [new Date(Date.UTC(x,y,z,...)), ...],
    ...
  ];
var table = new google.visualization.DataTable();
table.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
table.addColumn(...);
...
table.addRows(rows);
```

i've done

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
```

as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/29777575/3338098

and i've done

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  var googleChartLoaded = false;
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: function() {
    googleChartLoaded = true;
  }});
</script>
```

and even

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    googleChartLoaded = true;
  });
</script>
```

I have tried as per https://nealpoole.com/blog/2010/07/jquery-getjson-firefox-and-google-visualization-madness/

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  try {chart.draw(table, chartOptions);}catch(err) {
    console.err(err);
  }
}, 1000);
```

our issue is identical to https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148481/how-i-make-line-graph-on-android-device

how do I go about diagnosing this issue...
I assumed a google product would of been cross-browser compatible...

Comment: I ended up not using Google Charts API for obvious reasons and I am now using http://www.flotcharts.org/ without any complaint.

Comment: I am not sure reason of this error. But it is due to "new Date()". I got this error when calling new Date() but does not found the solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with exact this error message.
Here, the issue is with `options` object that is passed to `draw` function.

In my case, I had two options : `vAxis.ticks` and `hAxis.viewWindow`
The documentation says these options are only for continuous axis and my axes were continuous. However these were the problem. I took them out, and its working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when by mistake the data on xAxis was wrong:

2015-12-22T01:10:02,1
2015-12-22:01:15:01,1

My script saving the values because of my mistake was using : instead of T
on the date string.

Fixing the value to  YYYYMMDDTHH:MM:SS  solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've managed this problem or used something else, but I had the same problem and solved it by using this "new Date()" formatting that is proper to google charts :

```
new Date(Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds)
```

Try declaring your date this way and see if it solves your error.